# Change Background Color base React-select when its isDisabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

[this is from react-select documentation](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-selected-option-background-color-6re4j?file=/src/Select.js)

in this case, I will change color base of the select-field when

```
isDisabled={true}
```

to another color.

```
>     import React from "react";
>     import Select from "react-select";
>     
>     const colourOptions = [
>       { value: "red", label: "Red" },
>       { value: "green", label: "Green" },
>       { value: "blue", label: "Blue" }
>     ];
>     
>     const colourStyles = {
>       option: (styles, { data, isDisabled, isFocused, isSelected }) => {
>         // const color = chroma(data.color);
>         console.log({ data, isDisabled, isFocused, isSelected });
>         return {
>           ...styles,
>           backgroundColor: isFocused ? "#999999" : null,
>           color: "#333333"
>         };
>       }
>     };
>     
>     export default () => (
>       <Select
>         defaultValue={colourOptions[1]}
>         label="Single select"
>         options={colourOptions}
>         styles={colourStyles}
>         isDisabled={true}
>       />
>     );
```

my expectation, base color of the select-field can be changed to another color.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLVED**

```
<Select
    defaultValue={flavourOptions[2]}
    options={flavourOptions}
    theme={(theme) => ({
      ...theme,
      borderRadius: 0,
      colors: {
        ...theme.colors,
        primary25: 'hotpink',
        primary: 'black',
      },
    })}
  />
```

primary25 is condition when isDisable = true. You can find this in [react-select documentation](https://react-select.com/styles) (Overriding the theme)